# How to calculate the $\dot\gamma$ of $\gamma(s)=\Phi_s(\Gamma(s))$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Assume $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. $\Phi_s:M\rightarrow M$  is the 1-parameter  diffeomorphism group and
$$
\partial_s \Phi_s = X
$$
where $X$ is vector field. $\Gamma:[0,\tau]\rightarrow M$ is smooth curve. Let
$$
\gamma(s) = \Phi_s(\Gamma(s))
$$
then, how to show
$$
\dot\gamma = X + (\Phi_s)_* (\dot\Gamma)
$$
where $(\Phi_s)_*$ is the differential of $\Phi_s$.